# XSL Transformation: How to print all values in table

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation

I'm fully newbie in XSL transformation, and I need to print all values from XML into generated PDF via XSL transform without header, just values, like this:

```
--------------------------
|Cash         |  100     |
|Credit Card  |  46.1    |
|Debit Card   |  14      |
--------------------------
```

I have XML like this:

```xml
<Transaction>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Type>Cash</Type>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Type>Credit Card</Type>
    <Amount>46.1</Amount>
    </Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Type>Debit Card</Type>
    <Amount>14</Amount>
</Transaction>
```

I've created transformation, but it does't appear in result PDF:

```xml
  <xsl:template name="Transactions">
    <xsl:variable name="field">
      <Field FieldId="Type" Identifier="Type" Label="Type" Type="TextBox" Path="//Transactions" />
      <Field FieldId="Amount" Identifier="Amount" Label="Amount" Type="currency" Path="//Transactions" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="msxsl:node-set($field)/Field"/>
    <fo:table keep-together="auto" space-before="2mm">
      <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(10)" number-columns-repeated="2"/>
      <fo:table-body>
        <out:for-each select="//Transactions">
          <out:variable name="Type" select="Type"/>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="tableCell" font-weight="bold" number-columns-spanned="4" background-color="{$subheadingcolour}">
              <fo:block>
                <out:value-of select="Name"/>
              </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <out:for-each select="//Transactions[Type=$Type]">
            <fo:table-row>
              <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
                <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="tableCell">
                  <xsl:call-template name="field"/>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-row>
          </out:for-each>
        </out:for-each>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>
```

What I'm doing WRONG ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], where we can see (among other things) what namespace is bound to the prefix `out` and how - if at all - this template is called. And what does the `field` template do.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry, issue was resolved with another solution, just added some  <Field/> with index [i] in Path attribute